# how many images can I cache in my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management

I'm wondering how many images I can store in the iPhone documents directory so that I don't get any memory issues. I'm torn between caching images or loading them from a webserver every time the user wants to access them. There most likely won't be more than 10-20 images cached at any given time...

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a 2GB cap on the largest size of a single file in the `/Documents` folder. Other than that, you can store as many images as you want. iOS itself didn't put a limitation on how much space you can use on a device. So your space limit is the size of Flash on the device (i.e. 16GB, 32GB etc).

You might consider use the `/Library/Caches` instead because iCloud will attempt to sync the Documents folder (if entitlements are configured). I heard App being rejected by review for excessive use of the Documents folder. To get the path, call `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` with `NSCachesDirectory` and `NSUserDomainMask`.

Though a user can determine the size of space you are occupying in System Settings.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably cache as many files as available memory allows, but you absolutely should be safe having 10 - 20 images cached at any given time.

B.T.W., instead of using the documents directory, why not consider using the cache directory as He (+1 to him!) suggests?

[Here is a related question that shows how to get the size of the directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224642/size-of-nscachesdirectory-in-iphone).